# Dynamic programming for counting knapsack solutions

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problems, counting

Suppose the usual dynamic programming algorithm for the knapsack problem. If we swap the max    with an addition, does the modified algorithm compute all the solutions with benefit $\leq W$? I described the problem very briefly but I think anyone familiar with these notion wouldn't find any difficulty understanding what I ask. I think the complexity stays $nW$. Is it right?

Comment: You mention that you think that everything works. If so, it seems like you already know the answer. Do you have any specific doubts?

Comment: My main doubt is that the idea appears too simple. More precisely, if the optimization problem can be computed exactly in $nW$ it seems like we get the answer to the counting problem for free.

Comment: This is often the case in dynamic programming, for the reason you mention (you can replace $\max$ or $\lor$ with $+$).

Comment: Answers that allow only "yes" as an answer are not good for the site. If you have a specific question about your approach, please flesh out your post.

Comment: In addition -- what have you tried, and where did you get stuck?  The obvious way to answer your question on your own is to try to prove the algorithm correct (say, by induction).  Have you tried that?  If not, you should try it -- we expect you to make a significant effort before asking, and to show us what you've tried.

Comment: @Paramar: No, counting feasible solutions may be exponentially harder than finding the min or max weight of such a solution. E.g. finding min weight of an s-t path can be easily solved by a (min,+) circuit of Bellman-Ford in cubic time. But the corresponding counting problem is #P hard. The point: the BF circuit produces a lot of "garbage" - walks which are not simple paths, are not feasible solutions. But, unlike Sum, Min operation makes the circuit correct.